# Does anybody in the world knows why this PHP object call is not working?

Tags: php, class

I'm pretty new on PHP programming.
I'm trying to do something not very difficult, nonetheless following VERY BASIC code does not either return an error or displaying any output.
Playing around I guess it's related to $this->... line, I can't figure out why calling the function inside the object is not working.
Please Help !!!

```
class TargetBuy {

    public $ClientCode;
    public $Service;
    public $ServiceType; // Emissione, Cambio, Riemissione, Rimborso, NoShow... 
    public $RateType; // tipo tariffa
    public $Segment; // tratta
    public $CityHotel;
    public $TicketType; // one way or round trip
    public $AdvancePurchase;
    public $Penalty;
    public $Taxes; // 0=NotIncluded; 1=Included
    public $FinalPrice;

    function CalculateTB_Price() {  
        $this->ClientCode='Hello';
        echo $ClientCode;
    }

}

$TB = new TargetBuy;

$TB->CalculateTB_Price();
```

Comment: You're using `$this->ClientCode` for changing the property. But afterwards expect a local variable `$ClientCode` to exist (lack of `$this->`). Or are you referring to another problem? Describe your error, enable error_reporting, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because in the last row in the function, you print the var `$ClientCode` and not the var `$this->ClientCode`

Answer (score 3):

`$ClientCode` is not defined, please enable proper [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) which would have warned you about that. Instead, you have to use `echo $this->ClientCode;`.

You should read the basics about object oriented programming.

Comment: To enable full error reporting in any PHP script, use this:
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` ...although ideally you'd have your system set up to automatically display errors on your local/development/staging servers, and NOT display them on your production (live) server.

Comment: Even better: Enable in your php.ini config as described in the link in my answer ;)